# Regex for validating price in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :price, :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
```

My question is what the ?: is doing in the pricing format. Also, this regex is failing. It is not allowing 0.01 to be a valid price and, subsequently,  a valid item. Why?

From what I understand the regex is:
looking at the beginning, and looking for one ore more digits and then comes the ?: which I am confused about. What does it do?

Comment: Its a non capturing group

Comment: non-capturing group and `?` after the non-capturing group makes the whole non-capturing group as an optional one.